# Sonar ear exclude

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Good morning,
I have upgrade my installation of Sonar to the version 4.5.1 and use the latest plugin in Jenkins.
Now when I run a build with Sonar Analysis, Sonar tried to analyse the ear module and generate an error because there is no source in this module.

Answer (score 0):

It is the responsibility of your build to exclude the module. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Maven#AnalyzingwithMaven-ConfiguringtheSonarQubeAnalysis ("Excluding a module from SonarQube" analysis section) for an example with Maven.

Comment: By default, the ear module should not be scan for source directory.
This is very annoying to modify all our build projects.
I think that I'm not the only one in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus. 
Regards.